# Android Emulators (Memu Player, BlueStacks, LDPlayer) does not work

Tags: android-emulator, hyper-v

I have windows 10 and Nivada Quadro RTX 5000,
I am trying to install Android Emulator and tried the follwoing

```
Mumu: Give the following Error he core process of emulator has ended**
BlueStacks: Could not start blue stacks
LdPlayer:  g_bGestPowerOff fastpipeapi:cpp:1161 then suck  at 50%
```

I tried many many solution on the ineternet like disable hyper-v, using directX, OpenGl,
nothing works

Any help is this related to GPU?

Answer (score 0):

I use many emulators and I find [LDPLAYER](https://ldplay.mobi/en/) to work fine, however new versions often have problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).